# Eclipse - Convert to Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse Indigo, and I installed m2eclipse plugin. However, I can't see in Configure a Convert to Maven Project option.
I think I've installed the m2e for a newer eclipse version..Is there a way to install m2e for Eclipse Indigo? (can't find it in the market)

SOLVED: Finally I uninstalled and installed again m2e and now it works..i guess i did something wrong while installing it the first time.

Comment: Take a look at the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project

Comment: There is also the Eclipse wiki http://wiki.eclipse.org/Converting_Eclipse_Java_Project_to_Maven_Project

Comment: The problem is the Maven submenu isn't shown..I don't know if I did something wrong while installing it, I used Help -> Install New Software

Answer (score 5):

Run "mvn eclipse:eclipse" command in your project directory for convert project to maven project:

---

mvn eclipse:eclipse

OR (for web project)

mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0

Comment: -1 The here suggested usage of the [Maven eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) should not be mixed up with the [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) Maven Integration that is used by the questioner.

Comment: @Vinay This answer has nothing to do with the question (eclipse/m2e) plugin. Using the maven eclipse plugin as described here is completly different than using the m2e eclipse integration. You even will mess up your project if you use both approaches on the same project. Please tell my why do you think this answer is helpful?

Comment: No offence buddy. eventually m2e eclipse maven plugin to generate eclipse files. Even though the answers dont covers exact problem, it provide possible solution. I guess it is matter of opinion :)

Comment: Doesn't work: `Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory`

Comment: You probably didn't install your maven type project correctly. You have to first generate POM file. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704813/maven-generating-pom-file/11199865#11199865

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it through the Marketplace, try uninstalling it, and then reinstall it through "Install New Software" under Help. Enter this URL to get it from: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

That worked for me. If that URL doesn't work (or if you want an older version), check [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/).