# does installing third party jars in local repository needs pom file configuration?

Tags: java, maven

I made some jar files (using java and jar commands in CMD) but when I try to install them in a local directory (to use it as may local maven repository) by following command:

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

but maven gives me following error:

```
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory
```

which means that this command needs a pom file but which pom file (do I need to repackage my code with maven again!)

Comment: @prabugp if you just want to install the jar, then, an empty pom will suffice ? Anyway, I don't see why is it necessary just to install a 3rd party artifact.

Comment: @perencia you're right. It's not necessary. I was misled by the error message.
OP, Please see if you are bitten by this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11199865/2231632 ? I just executed this in a non-project directory and it worked for me. 
There is also a typo: it's -DartifcatId and that - is missing.

Comment: The missing hyphen before `DartifactId` is likely to be the problem - maven is trying to treat `Dartifact....` as the goal name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first go to your maven conf/settings.xml and define your local repo location:

```
Repository>E:/repo2/</localRepository>
```

then go CMD and type:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

NOTE: cause you don't have any pom in this case. you should define all the necessary parameters (groupid, artifactid, packaging and version) otherwise you will get an exception.

NOTE: if in your  string, contains spaces you need to surround it with a double quotation ("").

Also note that you can tell the location of your local repo explicitly, by parameter (-DlocalRepositoryPath).

If the above config doesn't work you can save all your config info in a pom file and reference it explicitly like below:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>  -DpomFile=<path to pom file>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to build the jar with Java but to use maven to build and install it.

1) Setup a new simple Maven project

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=yourProject -DartifactId=yourProjectsArtifactID -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
```

(http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-archetype-plugin-1.0-alpha-7/examples/simple.html)

2) Place the Java source for your jar into the resulting folder:
 *...\yourProjectsArtifactID\src\main\java*

3) If required declare the dependencies of your code 
which should be included in the classpath when compiling it to the POM.xml in *...\yourProjectsArtifactID*. You can do so by opening it in a text editor and replicating the existing entry for each jar that you would like to have in the classpath. Change the value in the scope tag to **compile** or remove it.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

4) Compile and install your jar

Run

```
mvn clean install
```

inside the folder in which the pom.xml resides: "...\yourProjectsArtifactID":