# When running "mvn test" on command prompt, error was encountered

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, automation, command-prompt

When running "mvn test" on command prompt, error was encountered. I need to run "mvn test" to test report JUnit plugin with Maven and Java.

Command prompt:

> [ERROR] Error executing Maven. [ERROR] 1 problem was encountered while
>   building the effective settings [FATAL] Non-parseable settings
>   C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin..\conf\settings.xml: end tag
>   name  must match start tag name  from line 102
>   \n -->\n...
>   @254:12> @ C:\Program
>   Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin..\conf\settings.xml, line 254, column 12

settings.xml

```
46<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
47          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
48          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
49  <!-- localRepository
50   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
51   |
52   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
53  -->
54  <localRepository>C:\Users\hiddenuser\.m2\repository</localRepository>
55  
56  <!-- interactiveMode
57   | This will determine whether maven prompts you when it needs input. If set to false,
58   | maven will use a sensible default value, perhaps based on some other setting, for
59   | the parameter in question.
60   |
61   | Default: true
62  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
63  -->
64
65  <!-- offline
66   | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when executing a build.
67   | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, artifact deployment, and others.
68   |
69   | Default: false
70  <offline>false</offline>
71  -->
72
73  <!-- pluginGroups
74   | This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e.
75   | when invoking a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group identifiers
76   | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not already contained in the list.
77   |-->
78  <pluginGroups>
79    <!-- pluginGroup
80   | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
81    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
82    -->
83  </pluginGroups>
84
85  <proxies>
86    <proxy>
87      <id>optional</id>
88      <active>true</active>
89      <protocol>http</protocol>
90      <!-- <username></username>
91      <password></password> -->
92      <host>hidden only</host>
93      <port>hidden only</port>
94      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
95    </proxy>
96  <proxies>
97  
98  <!-- servers
99   | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used within the system.
100  | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must make a connection to a remote server.
101  |-->
102  <servers>
```

Answer (score 1):

At line no : `92` you just comment the opening of `<servers>` and at line no `102` it's closing `<servers>`, the error says itself that, you pass the unnecessary comment on the tag please remove the comment sign..

`end tag name must match start tag name from line 102`

So update the file and execute it again and let us know that this solution is helped you or not

for reference visit the official site for more information

https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

for more refrence

[Error "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory" after executing maven command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348459/error-the-goal-you-specified-requires-a-project-to-execute-but-there-is-no-pom)

[maven generating pom file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704813/maven-generating-pom-file/11199865#11199865)

Answer (score 0):

Non-parseable settings

> C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin..\conf\settings.xml: end tag
>   name must match start tag name from line 102

Your settings.xml file has some syntax errors, try the below content:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- localRepository | The path to the local repository maven will use to 
        store artifacts. | | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository -->
    <localRepository>C:\Users\hiddenuser\.m2\repository</localRepository>

    <!-- interactiveMode | This will determine whether maven prompts you when 
        it needs input. If set to false, | maven will use a sensible default value, 
        perhaps based on some other setting, for | the parameter in question. | | 
        Default: true <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode> -->

    <!-- offline | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the 
        network when executing a build. | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, 
        artifact deployment, and others. | | Default: false <offline>false</offline> -->

    <!-- pluginGroups | This is a list of additional group identifiers that 
        will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e. | when invoking 
        a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group 
        identifiers | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these 
        are not already contained in the list. | -->
    <pluginGroups>
        <!-- pluginGroup | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin 
            lookup. <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup> -->
    </pluginGroups>

    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>optional</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <!-- <username></username> <password></password> -->
            <host>hidden only</host>
            <port>hidden only</port>
            <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>

    <!-- servers | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id 
        used within the system. | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven 
        must make a connection to a remote server. | -->
    <servers>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

You haven't specified the ending matching /servers and /settings in the settings.xml file, that's why you are getting 'Non-parseable settings' error.

Comment: This error comes when there is no pom.xml file in your directory from where you are executing

Comment: Is C:\Users\mnolasco contains pom.xml?

Comment: try to run `mvn clean install` and let see what output you are getting?

Comment: Can you share the file contents that `C:\Users\mnolasco` directory has? Use `dir` command to get files if you are working in windows or use `ls` for MacOS/Linux.

Comment: .eclipse, .m2, .p2, .tooling, .eclipse-workspace and my files

Comment: Ok... Seems like, this `C:\Users\mnolasco` directory doesn't contains `pom.xml` file - which is **POM stands for Project Object Model. It is fundamental unit of work in Maven. It is an XML file that resides in the base directory of the project as pom.xml. The POM contains information about the project and various configuration detail used by Maven to build the project(s). POM also contains the goals and plugins.** So you need to do change directory first using the `cd directoryName` which contains `pom.xml` file.

Comment: What I'm saying is, navigate to your maven project folder which has pom.xml then execute the maven commands from there.

Comment: my pom.xml file was placed under eclipse project folder together with the .settings, src, target folder and .classpath and .project file. is that what you are referring to as pom.xml file?

Comment: Yes, that pom.xml only

Comment: Is this your first maven project or have you created any other maven projects before?

Comment: this is my first maven project that i have created.

Comment: Ok great! Refer this [Link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) and try to do the same. If the Maven setup is done properly then this should work