# mvn command returns: [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

Tags: bash, maven, maven-archetype

Creating a project with `archetype:generate` in the same way as described in [Maven in 5 Minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).
Got this error:

```
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/mnt/c/Users/etomort/quartz-poc). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/mnt/c/Users/etomort/quartz-poc). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.
```

Since it is such a basic thing, I just got confused...

I checked these two questions:

- [Error “The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory” after executing maven command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348459/error-the-goal-you-specified-requires-a-project-to-execute-but-there-is-no-pom/42943502#42943502)
- [maven generating pom file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704813/maven-generating-pom-file/)

But neither the accepted answers solved the issue.
So, I am creating this question in case someone hits it and do not get it at first.

By the way, the Maven command entered is:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=quartz-poc -DarchetypeArtifactId= maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are on **Windows** and using the `cmd` command line or `PowerShell`, you need to wrap the arguments in quotes:

```
mvn archetype:generate "-DgroupId=com.mycompany" "-DartifactId=quartz-poc" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart" "-DarchetypeVersion=1.4" "-DinteractiveMode=false"
```

*On some machines, It works without the quotes on the `cmd` though.*

Comment: I was on Windows, but using WSL, which failed because I introduced spaces without noticing.

Comment: I keep forgetting this. This should mostly be the correct answer.

Comment: In WSL quotes are not really required.

Answer (score 3):

Watch out for **spaces** in `mvn` command!

Any spaces before and after `=` makes `mvn` fail:
[image]

In my question, the extra space is in `archetypeArtifactId`.
Though wherever it is, Maven will complain with the same message.

I inadvertently introduced spaces with `bash` auto-completion capability:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows and using the cmd command line:

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=quartz-poc -DarchetypeArtifactId= maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false`

If you are on Windows and using the PowerShell command line:

`mvn archetype:generate "-DgroupId=com.mycompany" "-DartifactId=quartz-poc" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart" "-DarchetypeVersion=1.4" "-DinteractiveMode=false"`